# Lint DOM/Component property value to camelCase

Tags: reactjs, eslint, tsx, typescript-eslint, eslint-plugin-react

I want to enforce the value of the `className` property on my DOM elements and components to be camelCase.

Example DOM element:

```
//bad DOM element ❌
<div className={'signinscreen_loading'}></div>

//bad DOM element ❌
<div className={'sign-in-screen-loading'}></div>

//good DOM element ✅
<div className={'signInScreenLoading'}></div>
```

Example component:

```
//bad component ❌
<Dropdown className={'signinscreen_loading'} />

//bad component ❌
<Dropdown className={'sign-in-screen-loading'} />

//good component ✅
<Dropdown className={'signInScreenLoading'} />
```

I have tried to resolve this with `"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention"` but cannot find a selector for the property value. It is quite easy to configure that properties should follow a convention, but not their values (attribute values)

I also cannot find a fitting rule from `ESLint` or `eslint-plugin-react`.